# HTMX load partials based on URL

Tags: django, htmx

Question: How do I have HTMX load a partial based on a URL that the user manually navigated to?

I am using HTMX to load HTML partials. All partials come from their own endpoint. So in this example, it is coming from `/h/library/1` where as the page is simply `/library/1`

My URL patterns are as such:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path("",               views.logged_in_home),
    path("library/<id>",   views.logged_in_home),
    path("h/library/<id>", views.show_library), # returns partial
]
```

The button to load the library looks like this (this is returned from `logged_in_home()`:

```
<a 
  hx-get="/h/library/1" 
  hx-push-url="/library/1" 
  hx-target="#page-content" 
  hx-swap="innerHTML"
>
Load Library 1
</a>

<div id="page-content"></div>
```

```
# show_library url
def show_library(request, id)
    return HttpResponse(f"Library {id} info.")
```

When I click the link, the partial gets loaded correctly into the div and the url updates with `/library/1`. However, when I manually navigate to `/library/1`, I get the homepage, but the partial doesn't load.

What the heck am I doing wrong? I see a lot of responses that suggest looking at the HTMX headers to determine if a partial or full page should be sent back, but I thought I could easily side-step that by using a designated api prefix like `/h/*`

Comment: Please share the respective views functions.

Comment: Are you using this for both endpoints? Could you also share the URL definitions?

Answer (score 0):

You're code is working correctly as you set it up, but you're going to the wrong URL for the partial to come through.

If you go to `/library/1` as you currently are, then based on your URL path `path("library/<id>", views.logged_in_home),` the **logged_in_home** view will be triggered, hence why you see the logged in page but no partial.

If you instead go to `h/library/1` (*note the **h** at the start)*, then you should indeed see the partial being loaded on its own and working correctly (because your URL `path("h/library/<id>", views.show_library)` will correctly return the HttpResponse partial for the given id, because it correctly triggers the **show_library** view).

---

NOTE: This is the behaviour of the site as you have set it up; it may not be the *wanted* behaviour of the site, in which case you may need to re-examine your views/urls and templates.

FWIW, when combining HTMX and Django I personally don't use the `hx-push-url` unless absolutely necessary, because it messes with the 'single-page magic' that HTMX brings to Django (and if I'm changing URLs anyway, then I can probably achieve most of what's needed with vanilla Django views).